# I know the limit of a subsequence exists, but how do I find it?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, proof-writing, proof-verification

I know intuitively that for:

$(a_n) = (1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4, ...)$

for any $m$ in the positive natural number there is a subsequence (m,m,m,..) that tends to m as n tends to infinity. I believe I must find a function from n to a function of n, which takes every element equal to m from $(a_n)$.

How would such a function be defined?

Comment: It seems fairly pointless to me to find an explicit formula. But here goes. The $k$-th "cycle" ends at the $k(k+1)/2$-th term.   We want the indices at which $m$ occurs. These are the indices $k(k+1)/2+m$, where $k$ is large enough, that is, $\ge m-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$m$ appears first after $m-1$ pattern cycles, at the index

$$
m+\sum_{i=1}^{m-1} i = \frac {m \left ( m+1 \right )}{2}
$$

after that we just have increments of $m+1, m+2,...$ i.e.

$$
a_n=m \iff n=m+ \frac {i \left ( i+1 \right )}{2} \ , \ i>m-2
$$

Answer (score 1):

The first occurence of $m$ occurs at the $\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$th position. The $i$th subsequent instance occurs after $m + (m+1) + \dots + (m+i-1) = i\cdot m + \frac{(i-1)i}{2}$th positions. So, in general, the $n$th occurence of $m$ will be at 
$$ 
\frac{m(m+1)}{2} + (n-1)m + \frac{(n-2)(n-1)}{2}
$$